# How to set the transition point of a linear-gradient background at a fixed pixel position?

Tags: html, css

I want to add styling to the bootstrap buttons to make them have two sections of different background colour.

Something like this:

[image]

I have tried this:

```
.btn{
    background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,.3) 30%);
}
```

But I can't use % to set where the transition between the colours should be, because then this will happen:

[image]

I need a way to set it by a fixed number of pixels.

This doesn't work:

```
.btn{
    background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,.3) 32px);
}
```

How could it be done?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @AmauryHanser for the solution (I wasn't far off! ;)) I have refined it into what I think are some pretty nice buttons, and keeping the code very neat and readable:

css:

```
.btn {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,.4) 36px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 36px);
    padding-left:0px;
}

.fas {
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}
```

html:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left fa-fw"></span>
    Avslutt uten å lagre
</a>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    <span class="fas fa-save fa-fw"></span>
    Lagre
</button>
```

result:

[image]

Note the use of `fa-fw`, which is setting fixed width of the FontAwesome icons. This is necessary in order to have the text start at the same pixel position on all buttons.

Comment: You can use **px**. `linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30px, rgba(0,0,0,.3) 30px)`, nothing more. Or a longer version `linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30px, rgba(0,0,0,.3) 30px, rgba(0,0,0,.3) 100%)`.

Comment: @AmauryHanser Indeed! :) Thanks! Feel free to write it up as an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: Done, happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can use pixels in your linear-gradient definition

```css
.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 40px, rgba(0,0,0,.3) 40px);
}
```

```html
<a class="btn">ICON Text</a>
```

You can see that I've used `to right` instead of `-90deg`, it's easier to understand.